# MySQL Backup with innobackupex error: Unrecognized character \x01; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at - line 1374

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb

Getting following error message:

```
Unrecognized character \x01; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at - line 1374.
170414 19:01:33 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: XXXXXXXX, password: set, port: not set, socket: not set
Error: Unsupported server version: '5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2'. Please report a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup
```

after running following command:

```
innobackupex --user=XXXXXXXX  --password=YYYYYYYYY --no-timestamp /data/backups/new_backup
```

Comment: open issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/1650526

Answer (score 0):

should be fixed in version 2.4.7 and version 2.3.8 https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/1651978, if you can still reproduce using the latest version please update the bug report